# How to distinguish changes made by the user from programmatic changes?

Tags: javafx-8

I'd like to react to changes made by the user and ignore the ones caused by my code.

For example, I've got a TextField that shows the name of an entry. When the user changes it, I want to save the change back so I've registered a change listener:

```
nameTextField.textProperty().addListener(
        (ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) -> {
            entry.setName(newValue);
            saveEntry();
        }
);
```

The problem is that this change listener is also triggered when I update the UI for new entry:

```
nameTextField.setText(entry.getName());
```

I can work around this by using a variable that indicates whether I'd like these changes to be applied, but this feels wrong, it "smells".

Also, this not only about TextFields. I have the same issue with ListViews and ComboBoxes.

Since I'm new to JavaFX and I think that this is a common issue I have a feeling that I'm missing something. So, how is this usually solved in JavaFX?

Comment: I don't think it's wrong. You're just using a workaround for a framework limitation

Comment: How about a boolean flag `setAutomatically` (was set by the program)? 1) Every time you set the value of the text field you have to set `setAutomatically` to true. 2) Everytime you read the value, you have to set `setAutomatically` to false. But it has the drawback that you can't use binding with it.

Comment: @Vertex: Thanks, but I already wrote that I can do that (and actually is what I currently do, though it's an `int` that's used like a semaphore instead to allow nesting), but it feels wrong. I have a feeling that there should be a better solution. So far it looks like there isn't, though.

Comment: Struggling with the same issue in Xamarin C# and similarly feel that the setProgramatically global just does not smell right